# How can I do multithreading on a dataframe?

Tags: python, multithreading, dataframe

I'm trying to do multithreading on dataframe with python like this blog:

http://blog.adeel.io/2016/11/06/parallelize-pandas-map-or-apply/

but I get this error:

> ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

which happens when executing this line

```
df = pd.concat(pool.map(func, df_split))
```

Could you please tell me what might be wrong?
Are there other ways to work on huge dataset using multithreading?

Comment: I've edited your post so it won't be subjective. If that changes your intent, feel free to edit it back.

Comment: the problem may be in either the datatypes you are loading or how you are loading the data. what kind of data are using/loading into the DataFrame, and how are you loading it? the steps in the article seem to run fine on my machine, can not reproduce that error that you are getting.

Comment: I'm loading a dataframe, and am working on one column ( rows are strings)